# R/shiny: problem with putting multiple data points in a reactive variable

Tags: r, shiny

i am trying to make a graph about child mortality, it works fine when i select just one country but it seems to exclude data points when i select multiple countries, i have included 2 images to show the problem. mdg1a is the data set containing the info for all years, all regions, all countries[this is how it looks for 1 country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsVe8.png) [Here you see the NA when selecting 2 countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsJbP.png)

```
  cir <- reactive({
    #cir stands for Countries In Region
    if (is.null(input$regionInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    if (input$regionInput == "All") {
      mdg1a
    } else {
      mdg1a %>%
        filter(region == input$regionInput)
    }
  })

  output$countryOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("countryInput", "country",
                sort(unique(cir()$country)),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = "")
  })


  filtered <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$regionInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    if (is.null(input$countryInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    cir() %>%
    filter(year >= input$yearInput[1],
           year <= input$yearInput[2],
           country == input$countryInput)
  })
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly--can't run it myself without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)--`input$countryInput` is a vector of 1 or more country names. So to check that each country is *among* those selected, not *equal to* those selected, you need `%in%`, not `==`

Comment: thank, the solution works. I didnt submit all the code because it might cause problems regarding plagiarism for my assignment.

Comment: You don't have to use the exact code from your assignment—you can always come up with ways to make an example or use an example that comes with a package that will replicate the issue